# how to read the last inserted field with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I've added some values into my tbl_class using

```
static DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
static tbl_Class _Class = new tbl_Class();
```

and in my add button:

```
_Class.ClassName = txtClass.Text;
_Class.Capacity = System.Convert.ToByte(txtCapacity.Text);
_Class.Place = txtPlace.Text;
_Class.TeacherName = txtTeacherName.Text;
_Class.Registered = 0;
_Class.ClassComments = txtDesc.Text;
db.tbl_Classes.InsertOnSubmit(_Class);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

now I need this last inserted row's id for next step. how do I retrieve it?
I used this code:

```
var query = (db.tbl_Classes
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.classID).Take(1)).ToArray();
```

to get the last ID but I don't know how to put this id in my int variable.
any help would be great.

Comment: Just check `_Class.classID` after `SubmitChanges()`.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `_Class` in the debugger after `SubmitChanges` to see if the new ID is set automatically?

Comment: what Adriano said will work

Answer (score 1):

After saving, try this:

```
var classID = _Class.classID;
```